# How to fix conflicting source password error?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, sshpass

I'm trying to set up a gitlab CI/CD.

1 of the script I use is :

```
sshpass -p $PRIVATE_KEY ssh -p $PORT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$SERVER01 "cd /var/www/html/app && export HISTIGNORE='*sudo -S*' && echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" | ( sudo -S -k git fetch && sudo -S -k git pull )"
```

as you can see I'm trying to update the application in my server.

FYI, I have already set up the variables in the gitlab CI/CD settings page.

But, when the job runs, it always returns this error message :

```
Conflicting password source
 Usage: sshpass [-f|-d|-p|-e] [-hV] command parameters
    -f filename   Take password to use from file
    -d number     Use number as file descriptor for getting password
    -p password   Provide password as argument (security unwise)
    -e            Password is passed as env-var "SSHPASS"
    With no parameters - password will be taken from stdin
    -P prompt     Which string should sshpass search for to detect a password prompt
    -v            Be verbose about what you're doing
    -h            Show help (this screen)
    -V            Print version information
 At most one of -f, -d, -p or -e should be used
```

I have already googled around, but found no clue.

Any clue would be much appreciated.

Comment: double quote `$PRIVATE_KEY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

So the above command worked for `master` branch, but it didn't work for `develop`, knowing this pattern, I checked the variables settings, then found out that I turned on the `Protect variable` flag, the flag says `Export variable to pipelines running on protected branches and tags only.`

Since `develop` is not a protected branch, I was thinking that the variable values were not passed into the pipeline.

So, I unchecked this flag for all variables and finally got it working.